# Kubernets 1.21.3 The recommended value for "clusterCIDR" in "KubeProxyConfiguration"

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I am trying to join new node to existing `v1.21.3` cluster with Calico CNI. join command giving `clusterCIDR` warning.

How to fix this subnet warning message?

```
# kubeadm join master-vip:8443 --token xxx --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:xxxx
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
[preflight] Reading configuration from the cluster...
[preflight] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -o yaml'
W0809 14:10:27.717696   75868 utils.go:69] The recommended value for "clusterCIDR" in "KubeProxyConfiguration" is: 10.201.0.0/16; the provided value is: 10.203.0.0/16
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env"
```

update:

I was using `10.201.0.0/16` during the cluster setup, later I changed to `10.203.0.0/16`. not sure where its still getting `10.201.0.0/16` subnet value.

Here is the sub net value.

```
# sudo cat /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml | grep cluster-cidr
    - --cluster-cidr=10.203.0.0/16

kubectl cluster-info dump | grep cluster-cidr
                            "--cluster-cidr=10.203.0.0/16",
                            "--cluster-cidr=10.203.0.0/16",
                            "--cluster-cidr=10.203.0.0/16",
```

**step to update pod CIDR  from 10.201.0.0/16 to 10.203.0.0/16**

1. using this command updated the  kubeadm-confg configmap
   `kubectl -n kube-system edit cm kubeadm-config`

`podSubnet: 10.203.0.0/16`

2. Updated kuber-controller-manger and restarted it.

`sed -i 's/10.201.0.0/10.203.0.0/' /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml`

**after updating the  IP.**

all config shows subnet as `10.203.0.0` but pods creating in `10.201.0.0' subnet.

```
# kubectl get cm kube-proxy -n kube-system -o yaml |grep -i clusterCIDR
    clusterCIDR: 10.203.0.0/16
# kubectl get no -o yaml |grep -i podcidr
    podCIDR: 10.203.0.0/24
    podCIDRs:
    podCIDR: 10.203.1.0/24
    podCIDRs:
    podCIDR: 10.203.2.0/24
    podCIDRs:
    podCIDR: 10.203.3.0/24
    podCIDRs:
    podCIDR: 10.203.5.0/24
    podCIDRs:
    podCIDR: 10.203.4.0/24
    podCIDRs:
    podCIDR: 10.203.6.0/24
    podCIDRs:
```

Comment: Could you add to the question following information: IP address of the main controller and worker node that are you trying to attach, output of the command `sudo cat /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml | grep cluster-cidr` and `kubectl cluster-info dump | grep cluster-cidr` (both from the main controller)? Did you edit somehow running configuration on the main controller? Which network did you use in `kubeadm` command - `sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr={network}`?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak added inline response to the post.

Comment: Could you please describe (tutorial, steps) how did you change your `clusterCIDR` network from `10.201.0.0/16` to `10.203.0.0/16` ? I am trying to replicate your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to replicate your issue. I got the same error. There is a need to update few other configuration files.

To fully change pods and nodes IP pool you need to update `podCIDR` and `ClusterCIDR` values in few configuration files:

- update ConfigMap `kubeadm-confg` - you did it already
- update file `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml` - you did it already
- update node(s) definition with proper `podCIDR` value and re-add them to the cluster
- update ConfigMap `kube-proxy` in `kube-system` namespace
- add new IP pool in Calico CNI and delete the old one, recreate the deployments

**Update node(s) definition:**

1. Get node(s) name(s): `kubectl get no` - in my case it's `controller`
2. Save definition(s) to file: `kubectl get no controller -o yaml > file.yaml`
3. Edit `file.yaml` -> update `podCIDR` and `podCIDRs` values with your new IP range, in your case `10.203.0.0`
4. Delete old and apply new node definition: `kubectl delete no controller && kubectl apply -f file.yaml`

Please note you need to do those steps for every node in your cluster.

**Update ConfigMap `kube-proxy` in `kube-system` namespace**

1. Get current configuration of `kube-proxy`: `kubectl get cm kube-proxy -n kube-system -o yaml > kube-proxy.yaml`
2. Edit `kube-proxy.yaml` -> update `ClusterCIDR` value with your new IP range, in your case `10.203.0.0`
3. Delete old and apply new `kube-proxy` ConfigMap: `kubectl delete cm kube-proxy -n kube-system && kubectl apply -f kube-proxy.yaml`

**Add new IP pool in Calico and delete the old one:**

1. Download the Calico binary and make it executable:

   ```
   sudo curl -o /usr/local/bin/calicoctl -O -L  "https://github.com/projectcalico/calicoctl/releases/download/v3.20.0/calicoctl"
   sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/calicoctl
   ```
2. Add new IP pool:

   ```
   calicoctl create -f -<<EOF
   apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
   kind: IPPool
   metadata:
     name: my-new-pool
   spec:
     cidr: 10.203.0.0/16
     ipipMode: Always
     natOutgoing: true
   EOF
   ```

   Check if there is new IP pool: `calicoctl get ippool -o wide`
3. Get the configuration to disable old IP pool -> `calicoctl get ippool -o yaml > pool.yaml`
4. Edit the configuration: -> add `disabled:true` for `default-ipv4-ippool` in the `pool.yaml`:

   ```
   apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
   items:
   - apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
     kind: IPPool
     metadata:
       creationTimestamp: "2021-08-12T07:50:24Z"
       name: default-ipv4-ippool
       resourceVersion: "666"
     spec:
       blockSize: 26
       cidr: 10.201.0.0/16
       ipipMode: Always
       natOutgoing: true
       nodeSelector: all()
       vxlanMode: Never
       disabled: true
   ```
5. Apply new configuration: `calictoctl apply -f pool.yaml`

   Excepted output of the `calicoctl get ippool -o wide` command:

   ```
   NAME                  CIDR            NAT    IPIPMODE   VXLANMODE   DISABLED   SELECTOR   
   default-ipv4-ippool   10.201.0.0/16   true   Always     Never       true       all()      
   my-new-pool           10.203.0.0/16   true   Always     Never       false      all()
   ```
6. Re-create pods that are in `10.201.0.0` network (in every namespace, including `kube-system` namespace): just delete them and they should re-create instantly in new IP pool range , for example:

   ```
   kubectl delete pod calico-kube-controllers-58497c65d5-rgdwl -n kube-system
   kubectl delete pods coredns-78fcd69978-xcz88  -n kube-system
   kubectl delete pod nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5-5n6nw
   etc..
   ```

   You can also delete and apply deployments.

After applying those steps, there is no warning about `clusterCIDR` value when adding new node. New pods are created in proper IP pool range.

Source:

- [Similar stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60176343/how-to-make-the-pod-cidr-range-larger-in-kubernetes-cluster-deployed-with-kubead)
- [Calico docs](https://docs.projectcalico.org/getting-started/clis/calicoctl/install)

Comment: Updated to `10.203.0.0` value but still pod creating with `10.201.0.0.` address. like this `coredns-85d9df8444-8dpql                                1/1     Running   0          10m     10.201.22.206`

Comment: Calico has the IP address range for pods, do we need to change this also to match podcidr?  `calicoctl get ippool -o wide
NAME                  CIDR            NAT    IPIPMODE   VXLANMODE   DISABLED   SELECTOR
default-ipv4-ippool   10.201.0.0/16   true   Always     Never       false      all()`

Comment: Good point, my mistake. I edited my answer how to fix it. Please check it and let me know if it is working.

Comment: I see the steps, its crayz, still pod getting created in `10.201.0.0` subnet. here calico pool `# calicoctl get ippool -o wide
NAME                  CIDR            NAT    IPIPMODE   VXLANMODE   DISABLED   SELECTOR
default-ipv4-ippool   10.201.0.0/16   true   Always     Never       false      all()
my-new-pool           10.203.0.0/16   true   Always     Never       true       all()
`

Comment: From the output that you sent, it seems you disabled `10.203.0.0` subnet, instead of `10.201.0.0` ;)

Comment: I added the excepted output to my answer.

Comment: Good  catch, I overlooked the output. Thanks for the help.